# How to check if browser window has been changed from windowed to full screen with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

For whatever the reason my code here:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  resizeFrontPage()
})
$(window).load(function(){
  $(window).resize()
})
```

doesn't work when I change the state of the window from full screen to windowed, but it does work when I'm resizing the window when it's already windowed. So I'd like to call out the function `resizeFrontPage()` when the state is being changed.

If it's a known bug, then just throwing a hint on how to fix it so that it works on `window.resize`, would be better of course.

Comment: Provide sample to replicate issue. FYI, even not related to your issue, but your code should be: `$(window).on('load resize', resizeFrontPage});`

Comment: Show an example of what you've tried in JSFiddle or something that people can check what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to check to see if it's full-screen or not.

**JQuery/JavaScript solution:**

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{
   if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
   this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() 
   {
       $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
   }, 500);
});


$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() 
{
   if ((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) 
     console.log("Full screen");
   else 
     console.log("Not full screen");
});
```